# Trim Canvas text to fit

Tags: node.js, canvas, discord.js

I need to trim some text to ensure it fits however, I am struggling as the size changes once I apply the font, I really have no idea how to go forward with this, with the following code I determined that the max width I would like to have is '363' and if it exceeds 363 (That is what 'w' should equal, at a maximum) trim the variable and add an ellipsis. Otherwise, if someone had a username longer than 363 with applied font and size, it would overlap and go off the screen, as seen in the photo. How would one do this?
CODE:

```js
let userGrab = message.author.username;

    function drawUsername(x, y, use, dis) {
      ctx.font = '34px Shapirit';
      ctx.fillStyle = '#FFFFFF';
      ctx.textAlign = 'left';
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
      ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;
      ctx.fillText(use, x, y);
      ctx.strokeText(use, x, y);
      w = ctx.measureText(use).width;

      ctx.font = '22px Shapirit';
      ctx.fillStyle = '#7F8384';
      ctx.textAlign = 'left';
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
      ctx.lineWidth = 0.25;
      ctx.fillText(dis, x + w + 4, y);
      ctx.strokeText(dis, x + w + 4, y);
    }

    drawUsername(270, 165.4, usergrab, discrim);
```

Long username:
[image: long user]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could loop over the word in question reducing its size (trimming) until it meets our max.
Sample code below:

```js
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawUsername(x, y, max, use, dis) {
  ctx.font = '34px Shapirit';
  ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;
  while (ctx.measureText(use).width > max) {
    use = use.substring(0, use.length-1);
  }
  ctx.fillText(use, x, y);
  ctx.strokeText(use, x, y);
  w = ctx.measureText(use).width
  

  ctx.font = '22px Shapirit';
  ctx.lineWidth = 0.25;
  ctx.fillText(dis, x + w + 4, y);
  ctx.strokeText(dis, x + w + 4, y);
}

drawUsername(20, 20, 150, "wwwwwwwwowowow", "123");
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas">
```

Comment: today you are asking questions, tomorrow you will be back here helping others...